# Shouldn't religious rebels disband after I've converted?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

An army of religious protestant rebels have sieged two of my provinces. In the meantime, I have converted to protestantism through the religion panel ... but the rebels apparently didn't get the memo, and they are still there.

I can accept their demands, to convert to protestantism, but that has other effects, which I am not interested in (lower religious tolerance).

Is this a bug, or do I really have to beat them or surrender to them?

Their army is fairly large, but they are on an island without ships, so they don't pose a threat right now, but I'd rather they didn't siege my provinces when we agree on our chosen flavour of christianity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it doesn't make sense to still have them after converting. But I guess that's a negative effect you are supposed be taking. Otherwise every player in your position would go with converting through the panel instead of accepting demands to avoid negative effects.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that religious rebels remaining after conversion are a bug though. As is, they will no do a single thing, now that looting was nerfed underground.

Answer (score 0):

Religion-based rebels also depend on the religion in their particular region. Unless both state and province converted, they have a reason to exist.

You wrote they can be neglected as they are on an island. Note that as of 1.8, rebels can move freely across water borders.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JohnoBoy I tried to address your hints in the edit